# How to create google calender event from php backend

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to create a google calender event whenever a user in my php site put an entry request.
Is it possible to create the event automatically from the server. If how to create it. Please help me to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look into Calendar API v3: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/
There are client libraries for php in the downloads section.

Comment: Thank you or the reply. But i dont know how to make it to accecpt server authentication as there are examples for client authentication only

Comment: I propose you describe your use-case in more detail. For example there are service accounts that let you authenticate as a service but there are restrictions: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount